# invoke function everytime a boolean becomes false in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, boolean

I'm trying to invoke a function everytime the "paused" property of a html audio element gets false.
I have a timer which shall count the time a audiofile is actually listened to (i also want to exclude the time while searching with the time bar).
I tried it with SetInterval checking all the time for the status of "paused". Unfortunately this isn't working accurately and quite often misses the status change and so lets the time counter count on.
Is there a simple way to invoke a function everytime a boolean changes?
Help would be very appreciated.

Thanks, f.

Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately this didn't do the trick.

Here's the Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h5 id="test">Audio Timer</h5>

<audio id="player" src="kerry.wav" controls></audio>
<form name="d">
    <input type="text" size="8" name="d2">
    <h1 id="time"></h1>
</form>

<script>
    var audio = document.getElementById("player");
    var millisec = 0;
    var seconds = 0;
    var timer;

    function display() {
        if (millisec >= 99) {
            millisec = 0
            seconds += 1
        } else
            millisec += 1
        document.d.d2.value = seconds + "." + millisec;
        timer = setTimeout("display()", 10);
    }

    function starttimer() {

        if (timer > 0) {
            return;
        }
        display();
    }

    function stoptimer() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }

    function startstoptimer() {
        if (timer > 0) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = 0;
        } else {
            display();
        }
    }

    function resettimer() {
        stoptimer();
        millisec = 0;
        seconds = 0;
    }

    setInterval(function () {
        var time = audio.paused;
        if (time == false) {
            startstoptimer();
        }
    }, 1);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately the SetInterval(function().. isn't fast enough to track the audio.paused. which seems is what i need. As you can see this code always does start the timer, but quite often it doesn't stop it when you press pause or when you use the time bar to seek through the audio.

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a while (true) my page didn't even load.
 But I finally brought it to life by adding two event listeners listening to "playing" and "pause" which invoke the startstoptimer function.

```
audio.addEventListener("playing", startstoptimer);
audio.addEventListener("pause", startstoptimer);
```

those two lines were all it needed :) 
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that calls your audio tag

```
var yourAudio = document.getElementById("audio")
```

And then

```
yourAudio.onpause=YourFunction()
```

If that is not what you are looking for, post your code or part of it, give us more information.

Comment: @Fl. you said the setInterval was not fast enough. Try something like `while(2>1){}`, I think it is faster